# how to set default ping6 interface

Tags: linux, ping, ipv6, centos6

while trying to ping an ipv6 address I want to simply use ping6 IPv6Address but it seems we need to specify interface as well like ping6 IPv6Address -I eth0 I tried but could not successfully configure ping6 to automatically send ICMP(v6) packets through eth0, please help

Answer (score 2):

The notation you need to use depend on the scope of the address. Some IPv6 addresses have link-local scope and need a scope identifier. They could look like `fe80::1%eth0` or `ff02::1%wlan0`. The naming convention for the scope differs between operating systems.

For addresses which have global scope, there is no need for specifying scope. For example `ping6 2001:db8::1` is a perfectly valid command with no scope.